# Encoding error when knitr -> LaTeX -> PDF

Tags: r, input-encodings, knitr, rstudio

I have a document written in knitr. I can export it to HTML and docx, but not PDF for some reason. The Rmd file is here http://cl.ly/dJka?_ga=1.30252732.2076817589.1442770201

It says

```
! Package inputenc Error: Unicode char \u8:￼ not set up for use with LaTeX.

See the inputenc package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.429 ￼

Try running pandoc with --latex-engine=xelatex.
pandoc: Error producing PDF from TeX source
Error: pandoc document conversion failed with error 43
In addition: Warning message:
In native_encode(text) :
  some characters may not work under the current locale
Execution halted
```

The funny thing is that it says almost the same thing for docx, but there it goes fine.

```
Output created: a22.docx
Warning message:
In native_encode(text) :
  some characters may not work under the current locale
```

Then I looked at the error codes in the console and saw

```
label: plot colgpa and residuals
cropping a22_files/figure-latex/plot colgpa and residuals-1.pdf
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
    LC_ALL = (unset),
    LC_CTYPE = "en_SE.UTF-8",
    LANG = "en_SE.UTF-8"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
PDFCROP 1.38, 2012/11/02 - Copyright (c) 2002-2012 by Heiko Oberdiek.
==> 1 page written on `a22_files/figure-latex/plot colgpa and residuals-1.pdf'.
  |..........
```

So I thought it was becuase if I have a "code chunk" with graph output in Rmd I cannot name it with spaces since R have nowehere to put the graph - a dir cannot contain spaces. So I deleted them.

Now I get fewer errors, but still I canno render it. The whole error code is

```
During startup - Warning messages:
1: Setting LC_CTYPE failed, using "C" 
2: Setting LC_COLLATE failed, using "C" 
3: Setting LC_TIME failed, using "C" 
4: Setting LC_MESSAGES failed, using "C" 
5: Setting LC_MONETARY failed, using "C" 


processing file: a22.Rmd
(*) NOTE: I saw chunk options "q4 colgpa = athlete + sat"
 please go to http://yihui.name/knitr/options
 (it is likely that you forgot to quote "character" options)
Error in base::parse(text = code, srcfile = NULL) : 
  1:11: unexpected symbol
1: alist( q4 colgpa
              ^
Calls: <Anonymous> ... withCallingHandlers -> eval -> parse_only -> <Anonymous>
In addition: Warning message:
In native_encode(text) :
  some characters may not work under the current locale
Execution halted
```

I post it here since knitr does Rmd -> LaTeX -> PDF and I do not see the latex-step.

Comment: What system are you working on?
Do you also get the `Locale` error during start-up of R? You could try setting it: `Sys.setlocale(category = "LC_ALL", locale = "en_SE.utf8")`

Comment: @mrub I'm on OSX. Where do I write that code?

Comment: This is R code which you can put in one of your R chunks.

Comment: @mrub should I put them in one or all? If I need to set them in all, can I use them in "global" somewhere?

Comment: Try setting the locale in your first R chunk. It should be valid for the entire session, i.e. all following code.